# Tinker no me permite buscar un usuario

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, tinker

Estoy intentando buscar un usuario desde tinker que tiene la id 40, pero me da un error conforme la sintaxis esta mal..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que campos tiene tu tabla Usuario?

Comment: Seguro que ya ingresaste a tinker?

Comment: por lo que veo no estas ejecutanfo tinker, estas desde el bash, debes darle php artisan tinker y luego si ejecutas la busqueda

Comment: tenias razon @NicolasAldana, publica respuesta y te lo doy por valido ,gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que veo no estas ejecutando tinker, debes darle el comando

```
   php artisan tinker
```

y luego si ejecutas la busqueda dentro del bash